# python set update with list or set(list)

Tags: python, list, set, iterable

I encountered the following code

```
l = [1, 2]
s = set()
# the same results from the following two
s.update(set(l))    
s.update(l)
```

why these two get the same results? Is it because both are iterables?

Answer (score 4):

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects):

> Note, the non-operator versions of update(), intersection_update(), difference_update(), and symmetric_difference_update() will accept any iterable as an argument.